# Como o Git salva os arquivos editados de um commit?

Tags: git

Eu entendi que `git add` cria a hash dos arquivos alterados no projeto e adiciona essa hash como referência ao *staging*. No `git commit` ele cria uma hash para todos os arquivos do projeto, salva como uma tree e cria um objeto do commit com essa hash da tree, a hash do commit anterior etc. Porém, em momento nenhum ele faz referência aos arquivos editados.

Como o Git sabe quais arquivos foram editados em um commit?

Comment: talvez ajude https://shalithasuranga.medium.com/how-does-git-work-internally-7c36dcb1f2cf

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que para complementar a resposta do Francisco, todo arquivo que é manipulado pelo git, é gerado uma chave SHA, desde seus blobs e tree, é um emaranhado de SHA, se tornando único a cada arquivo, e qualquer espaço dado diferente no arquivo, muda-se essa SHA, e se por ventura, você conseguir voltar exatamente a situação anterior, a SHA tambem será igual novamente. Assim o Git consegue saber se foi manipulado algo no arquivo. Os commits é para voce comentar e saber visualmente o que foi feito.

Obs.: SHA é uma chave de criptografada de 40 caracteres unico ao que é feito no documento.

Apesar de ser wikipedia, explica melhor o que é SHA.
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms